# Best way to deal with schema issues across multiple branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, activerecord, schema

I'm running a rails app and one of my new branches uses the "type" column in our table for single table inheritance. However, when I switch back to our production branch, I'm forced to rake db:reset and lose all my local data because I get an error since we have the type column in a table still even though it isn't being used. Is there a better way to handle this?

(this is all on my development environment)

Answer (score 0):

You should use different enviroments for different branches! Each enviroment has their own properties files, so you can setup different database tables without any problem.

Only you need to start the server with the following param:

rails server -e enviroment_name

Comment: I have different environments but all environments will be development when i'm using my dev environment...so i'm not sure your solution applies

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood the question, but I think that there isn't a general answer, each case is different from another.

What would resolve these branch hops is using the `seeds.rb` file to populate the db after a `db:reset` so you always have dummy data to work with.

Comment: hmm...this might be a good suggestion. i'll check it out. thanks